# Android AsyncTask re-runs when activity is opened

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my App the user has to login.

- They open the app on the login page
- They enter email/password and hit login
- A LoadingScreenActivity is opened that has a swirly circle and is running an AsyncTask     that goes to my database and retrieves all the users info

After the AsyncTask is completed it starts an intent to launch MainPageActivity.

There are two problems with this at the moment:

1. If the user logs in and then goes to the home screen while the app loads the MainPageActivity will open as soon as it is ready (on top of the existing home page) even though the app has been minimised
2. If the user logs in and then goes to the home screen while the app loads and then returns to the loading screen the AsyncTask will complete twice over

For problem 1. At the moment my onPostExecute() method in LoadingScreenActivity looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        //open the main page  
        Intent mainPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class);                             
        mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
        startActivity(mainPage);
    }
```

Is there a way I could detect in this method if the main page activity should be opened yet?

For problem 2. I've hit a complete road block on this, is there a way to detect if the activity has simply been re opened rather than started for the first time? I'd really appreciate any tips on this, I'm quite new to android so I'm not even convinced an Async task is the way to go with this.

Thanks for your time

LoadingScreenActivity.java

```
    public class LoadingScreenActivity extends Activity implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {

private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";
private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

    // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
    // retained across a configuration change.
    if (mTaskFragment == null) {
      mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
      fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_title);  
    TextView progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_progress);  

    title.setText(R.string.app_name);
    progress.setText("Loading your info");
}



@Override
public Context onPreExecute() { 

    return getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) {   
}

@Override
public void onCancelled() {
    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(login);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
    //open the main page  
    Intent mainPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class);                             
    mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mainPage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    startActivity(mainPage);
}

}
```

and TaskFragment.java

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {


  static interface TaskCallbacks {
    Context onPreExecute();
    void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
    void onCancelled();
    void onPostExecute();
  }

  private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
  private DummyTask mTask;


  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;


  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // Create and execute the background task.
    mTask = new DummyTask();
    mTask.execute();
  }


  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
  }


  private class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
  Context context;
  boolean running = true;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  if (mCallbacks != null) {
    context = mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
  }
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
    //Get the current thread's token  
    synchronized (this)  
    {
        if(running){
            DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            dbHandler.populateSQLiteDatabase();
        }

    }  

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
  if (mCallbacks != null) {
    mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(percent[0]);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
  if (mCallbacks != null) {
    mCallbacks.onCancelled();
  }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
  if (mCallbacks != null) {
    mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
  }
}


  }
}
```

Comment: did you check `onConfigurationChanged()` in loading screen activity . Just implement it lemme also drop an answer .

Comment: with re opened you mean navigated from any other activity ?

Comment: Also show your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Jibran, with re opened I mean if you go to the home screen and then restart the app by clicking it's icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your activity in the manifest just add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
 and in the activity implement this

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that my async task already works perfectly if you rotate the screen. I am using it in conjunction with TaskFragment. I will edit my question now to include LoadingScreenActivity and TaskFragment.

Comment: I've posted my code, I didn't post it originally because it's messy. But I should have mentioned it deals with orientation changes.

Comment: Wait that was be being silly, sorry I have got it working now, that totally fixes problem 2!! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: sorry I don't have enough rep to vote your answer up

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, i don't really understand your first problem.
About the second one, there are a couple of ways depending on your minimum API level. Starting from API 14 you may register ActivityLifecycle Callbacks inside an Android Application. To do this, i would recommend:

1. Inherit Android application with a custom one
2. Replace the Android application in your manifest
3. inside your custom application register itself as activity lifecycle listener
4. inside the abstract methods you get the instance of the currently applying activity (may safe `object.name()` in a String)
5. depending on your handling you may safe a boolean value or whatever to identify the behaviour
6. methods inside your custom application are accessible by casting `(MyCustomApplication)getApplication()`

Heres a snippet:

```
package com.example.preferencestest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyCustomApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private String storedActivity;
    private Boolean doOrNot = false;

    public MyCustomApplication() {}
    public Boolean getDoOrNot() { return doOrNot;}
    public void setDoOrNot(Boolean doOrNot) { this.doOrNot = doOrNot; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    // these two are the most important ones since they will be fired everytime
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if (activity.getClass().getName().equals(storedActivity)) {
            doOrNot = true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        storedActivity = activity.getClass().getName();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) { }
    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) { }
    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) { }
    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) { }
    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) { }
}
```

inside your Manifest you MUST declare this new Applicationclass like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.preferencestest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.preferencestest.MyCustomApplication"
{...}
```

Then inside your Activity you may do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Boolean whatToDo = ((MyCustomApplication)getApplication()).getDoOrNot();
}
```

Using onConfigurationChanged has a couple of disadvantages. There are a couple of actions (placing device in dock, turning display and so on) which restart the Activity. You should rather save the current state of the Activity with

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already accepted the answer above as solving my problem. I will have a look at implementing this shortly. Sorry I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer